# Return even and odd elements of the array

Tags: javascript

I try to make a function to return first the odd elements of the array and then the even ones. Tell me how to do it? thanks

```
export const sameParityFilter = (arr = []) => {
let result = arr.filter(function(elem) {
if (arr % 2 == 0) {
    return true;
} if (arr % 2 != 0) {
    return false;
}
});
sameParityFilter([[-1, 0, 1, -3, 10, -2]]);
sameParityFilter([[2, 0, 1, -3, 10, -2]]);
```

Comment: So your expected output is `[[-1, 1, -3], [0, 10]]` in the first case?

Comment: @Taxel, no [-1,1, -3]

Comment: So the first element decides if you want to filter even or odd values?

Comment: @Taxel I need to return an array with even and odd values

Comment: check how `.filter` is working first. then check input array... should it be as array of arrays or not

Comment: Your filter function is somewhat wrong

Answer (score 2):

I didnot understand the code you have written so I wrote a simple code which shall help you

```js
const sameParityFilter = (arr = [], filter = "odd") => {
    const odds = []
    const evens = []

    for(item of arr) {
        if(item % 2 === 0) {
            evens.push(item)
        } else {
            odds.push(item)
        }
    }

    if(filter === "odd") {
        return odds
    } else {
        return evens
    }
}

alert(sameParityFilter([1 , 7 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 1 , 2] , "even"))

alert(sameParityFilter([1 , 7 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 1 , 2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sameParityFilter = (arr)=>{
  let odd = [];
  let even = [];
  arr.forEach(elem => {
    if(elem%2==0)
        even.push(elem)
    else
      odd.push(elem)
  
  })

  return [odd,even];
}

console.log(sameParityFilter([-1, 0, 1, -3, 10, -2]));
console.log(sameParityFilter([2, 0, 1, -3, 10, -2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an output array filled with all the odd entries which are then followed by all the even entries of an input array, while preserving the order of values' appearance in the input array, try using `Array.prototype.reduce` with a two-dimensional array accumulator argument, followed by a call to `Array.prototype.flat` to concatenate the odd and even sub-arrays:

```js
const oddsFirst = arr=>arr.reduce((acc,n)=>(acc[n&1^1].push(n), acc),[[],[]]).flat()

console.log(oddsFirst([-1, 0, 1, -3, 10, -2]));
```

- References for `Array.prototype` methods `reduce` and `flat` are available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/), and
- The expression
  `n&1^1` get the least significant binary digit of `n` by anding `n` with `1`, followed by exclusive-oring the result with `1` to flip ones to zeros and zeroes to ones. The result is zero for odd numbers and one for even numbers.
- If you don't want to flatten the 2D array, leave out the `.flat()` call.